# Browse and set img src using javascript/JQuery in Asp.net mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `<img/>` tag in my .cshtml page..

```
<img id="ImageID" alt="" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

I need to set src attribute dynamically by selecting the image file path using file control.

I tried the following code in my Js page, but it is not working.

```
var image_path = $("#fileControl").val();

$("#ImageID").attr('src', 'url(' + image_path + ')');
```

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: is url in image_path  is correct?

Comment: Why not do it like that? `$("#ImageID").attr('src', $("#fileControl").val());`

Comment: You're saying that you're setting it dynamically, which suggests to be that you are actually needing a live event rather than `.val()`. Otherwise you could just set the javascript with your razor anyway, in the same way you're setting the #fileControl value

Comment: @Cris yes. I tried to alert the image_path. It is showing as c:/documents/.../image.jpg. it is reflecting in tag like this. <img id="drawAreaImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  src="C:/Users/james.s/Desktop/pics/background.jpg" />. I can see the image while placing the img tag in ordinary html page. but it not reflecting in my application.

Comment: To check, I tried following codes in my .cshtml page. 

1. <img id="drawAreaImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  src="~/Images/background.jpg" />

2. <img id="drawAreaImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"  src="c:/Users/james.s/Desktop/pics/kopieren/background.jpg" />

2nd one didnt work.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, as it sounds different to what the question is asking? Maybe alter the question to reflect a bit more information also?. `~` will be relative to the root of the website, `c:` will be your local file. The latter will not work on a website.

Comment: @danrichardson $("#fileControl").val(); gives the local file path. i need to set that path to the img src.

Comment: My answer will help you with that, however thinking about it you may also need to add `file://` to the start of the path when setting it to `#ImageID`

Answer (score 0):

To change it to a live event, so that it changes as when your `#fileControl` value changes, do:

```
$("#fileControl").on('change', function(){
  $("#ImageID").attr('src', 'url(file://' + $(this).val() + ')');
})
```

...but obviously the above may change slightly (on, bind, live), depending on you jQuery version

Comment: i was able to set img src in when it is in html page. but i am having the <img/> tag in .cshtml page. How to resolve path in mvc 4?

Comment: Just to check i hard coded the img tag  in my .cshtml page. 
1. <img id="drawAreaImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="~/Images/background.jpg" />
2. <img id="drawAreaImg" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="c:/Users/james.s/Desktop/pics/kopieren/background.jpg" /> 2nd one didnt work.

Comment: as you suggested i tried adding 'file://' before the URL. when i place the code in .html page, it works. But when i placed it in .cshtml page it didn't. 

I took the following code from my IE8's Developer tools source code.
<img id="ImageID" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="file:///C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"/> 

Any issues with the URL???